# How to extract information from a message of an imported module?

Tags: functional-programming, elm

I am trying to take the "buttons" example (http://elm-lang.org/examples/buttons) and import it from another module that would display several of them on the same page.

I am afraid that I am still thinking with components in mind, but I just want to share it anyway.

I created Main.elm that load a slightly modified version of the buttons example (Buttons.elm).

In Main.elm I have a list of Buttons.Model that I use to generate the list of buttons.

I am stucked now because I don't know how to get the necessary info from Buttons.Msg in Main.elm

To see the code:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/lucamug/elm-multiple-buttons.git
$ cd elm-multiple-buttons/
$ elm-package install
$ elm-reactor
```

and open

- http://localhost:8000/source/06/buttons.elm
- http://localhost:8000/source/06/main.elm

-- Solution

The problem, as pointed out by Chad Gilber in the accepted answer, was in this line:

```
(List.indexedMap (\position buttons -> Html.map Tag (Buttons.view position buttons)) model.buttonsList)
```

this is the correct version

```
(List.indexedMap (\position buttons -> Html.map (Tag position) (Buttons.view buttons)) model.buttonsList)
```

If you are interested in this implementation, you can find more details in this post https://medium.com/@l.mugnaini/recycling-elm-code-transforming-it-in-a-module-4946d5ccd3cd

Comment: please paste the key code that needs consideration in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to update your `Tag` constructor to include the array index.

The relevant changes to code are:

```elm
view model =
    div []
        (List.indexedMap (\position buttons -> Html.map (Tag position) (Buttons.view position buttons)) model.buttonsList)

type Msg
    = Tag Int Buttons.Msg

update msg model =
    case msg of
        Tag position button_Msg ->
```

And you'll want to remove the hardcoded `position = 1` in your `update` function.

[This Pull Request](https://github.com/lucamug/elm-multiple-buttons/pull/1) outlines the changes necessary.